# Datatables Header Resize

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

Im using the following options for my table

```
$('#test').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    bInfo: false,
    scrollY: "600px",
    scrollX: "700px",
    scrollCollapse: true,
});
```

This works great for everything I need except for one thing, when I use a hamburger menu to collapse or expand a sidebar, the tables header does not resize correctly. Below is the top right corner of my table after the sidebar has been collapsed

[image]

As you can probably see, the body and the filter are both on the correct plane but our header is too narrow.

I attempted to use the `scrollResize` option but that does not apply to the issue at hand.

EDIT: I have one column that is hidden currently. It would seem that datatables lacks the ability to correctly calculate a resize with hidden elements. To resolve this I will attempt to replace hidden data by using the `data-*` attribute.

[Source](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/52980/table-header-not-resizing)

EDIT 2: I attempted the solution above but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by manually triggering a header resize event each time the hamburger menu was clicked.

```
$("#sidebarToggle").on("click", function(){
    $('#test').dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
});
```